# How to turn off power management for external hard drive (Seagate GoFlex)?

Tags: mount, power-management, external-hdd

I bought this 2tb Segate GoFlex this last Black Friday and since then every 15 minutes or so the drive spins down, and then a little while later completely dismounts. Very annoying.
From what I understand you could turn this off using the including Windows and Mac only software. This function and what controls it isn't proprietary, right? There has to be something that'll let me set it in Ubuntu... Anyone have any suggestions?

Also, I formatted it to EXT4. Hope I didn't screw myself up. :/

Answer (score 2):

You can dissable the powermanagement of your device with the following command (no powermanagement = no spindown - no standby for the harddrive)

```
hdparm -B 255 /dev/sdX
```

**replace sdX with the name of your harddrive**

This will **only last** till you restart your pc.

If you want it to be permanent:
write the command in this file

```
/etc/rc.local
```

Comment: I just tried. Gave me this:

/dev/sdf1:
 setting Advanced Power Management level to disabled
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD failed: Invalid exchange
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Invalid exchange

Comment: @RPG `/dev/sdf1` looks wrong - try `/dev/sdf` (the drive) rather than `sdf1` (the partition). If the drive does not accept -B, try some of the other options; like `-S0` (disable spindown) or `-S251` (spindown after 5.5 hours). See the [hdparm man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hdparm) for the full list, for most drives at least some of the commands work.